# How do I manually transform an IPv4 address into an IPv6 address?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, subnet

I would like to know if there is any manual method in transforming an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address without the use of an conversion calculator or tool. For example:

I have an IPv4 address and it is given as:

`129.130.100.11`

and when it is transformed the answer is given as:

`0::FFFF:8182:640B`

Are there any formula used to perform such transformation?

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For IPv6, the octets are usually represented as hexadecimal numbers, whereas IPv4 uses decimal.  So, an **extremely** simplified method is to first convert each of the decimal octets (8 bits) to hexadecimal:

```
129 becomes 81
130 becomes 82
100 becomes 64
11 becomes 0B
```

Then concatenate the results with a colon between the first two and the last two octets:

```
8182:640B
```

And add `::FFFF:` to the front of the string:

```
::FFFF:8182:640B
```

There are however a few different formats for an IPv6 address.  I left these out above as you can see they all include some type of decimal-hexadecimal conversion and some simple string formatting.  Other alternatives include:

- **6 to 4 address**:

  - 2002:8182:640B:0:0:0:0:0
  - 2002:8182:640B::
- **IPv4-mapped** address:

  - 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.130.100.11
  - ::FFFF:129.130.100.11
  - ::FFFF:8182:640B
- **IPv4-compatibility** address:

  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:129.130.100.11
  - ::129.130.100.11
  - ::8182:640B

Comment: _IPv4-Compatible_ IPv6 addresses are deprecated since 2006 (RFC 4291). You can savely ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is correct as well, a valid IPv6 address may end with decimal rts as well, exactly in order to provide this sort of things.

You can just write

```
::FFFF:129.130.100.11
```

and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, left it out for brevity, but have updated my answer to include the other possible formats.